# While choosing particular name in dropdown filter(Slicer in visual) in powerbi loads data very slowly (Using direct query mode)

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I use direct query in powerBI to fetch data using sql query.
In the visual I have one slicer as dropdown list and table to show all data fetched from Db.
In slicer have data's like name, while trying to filter the data by name, clicking check box in the dropdown, then the table have circle like symbol at top right corner which I believe it's for 'loading' symbol. But when choosing name it takes long time to filter the data and to show the loaded data in a table. Have any suggestions to speed up the data loading in table while choosing slicer filter.

Comment: Your slicer is from "directquery" or from an imported table? Verify what query come to your datasource when you slice your visual.

Comment: From direct query. And table results from direct query too.

Comment: There may be a problem with your source database -> try to verify what query goes to your db (or problem with network if you try to fetch a high volume of data). You can check if query reduction is an option for you (if you have multiple filter/slicer multiple values to select):

https://youtu.be/4kVw0eaz5Ws?t=191